# Ember js Build Error (broccoli-persistent-filter:EslintValidationFilter)

Tags: node.js, ember.js, npm-install, ember-cli, broccolijs

After cloning the repository from Github then install npm and try to execute ember s. but I got this error. Then I delete node modules directory and package-lock.json file and install npm again. But i can't solve it.I am googling this error but can't solve it. Plz, Help me.
Here is my Error:

```
Build Error (broccoli-persistent-filter:EslintValidationFilter) in helpers/flash- 
message.js

Package subpath './lib/util/traverser' is not defined by "exports" in 
/home/ag/Office/ecommerce/front-end/node_modules/eslint/package.json


Stack Trace and Error Report: /tmp/error.dump.a671c24c39f689554c47c73d068f7e9f.log
```

My Package.json:

```
{
"name": "front-end",
"version": "0.0.0",
"private": true,
"description": "Small description for front-end goes here",
"repository": "",
"license": "MIT",
"author": "",
"directories": {
"doc": "doc",
"test": "tests"
},
"scripts": {
"build": "ember build",
"lint:hbs": "ember-template-lint .",
"lint:js": "eslint .",
"start": "ember serve",
"test": "ember test"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@ember/jquery": "^0.6.0",
"@ember/optional-features": "^0.7.0",
"broccoli-asset-rev": "^3.0.0",
"ember-ajax": "^5.0.0",
"ember-aria-tabs": "^3.0.0",
"ember-auto-import": "^1.10.1",
"ember-cli": "~3.12.0",
"ember-cli-app-version": "^3.2.0",
"ember-cli-babel": "^7.7.3",
"ember-cli-bootstrap-4": "^0.12.0",
"ember-cli-dependency-checker": "^3.1.0",
"ember-cli-eslint": "^5.1.0",
"ember-cli-flash": "^2.1.0",
"ember-cli-form-data": "^2.1.1",
"ember-cli-htmlbars": "^3.0.1",
"ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile": "^2.1.0",
"ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.8.2",
"ember-cli-moment-shim": "^3.8.0",
"ember-cli-sass": "^10.0.1",
"ember-cli-shims": "^1.2.0",
"ember-cli-sri": "^2.1.1",
"ember-cli-swiper": "^1.0.6",
"ember-cli-template-lint": "^1.0.0-beta.1",
"ember-cli-uglify": "^2.1.0",
"ember-composable-helpers": "^2.4.0",
"ember-concurrency": "^1.3.0",
"ember-cp-validations": "^4.0.0-beta.12",
"ember-crumbly": "^3.0.1",
"ember-data": "~3.12.0",
"ember-drag-drop": "^0.9.0-beta.0",
"ember-export-application-global": "^2.0.0",
"ember-fetch": "^8.1.0",
"ember-font-awesome": "^4.0.0-rc.4",
"ember-load-initializers": "^2.0.0",
"ember-local-storage": "^1.7.2",
"ember-maybe-import-regenerator": "^0.1.6",
"ember-modal-dialog": "^3.0.1",
"ember-moment": "^8.0.1",
"ember-pickr": "^2.2.1",
"ember-power-select": "^3.0.2",
"ember-qunit": "^4.4.1",
"ember-resize": "^0.3.4",
"ember-resolver": "^5.0.1",
"ember-source": "~3.12.0",
"ember-toggle": "^7.1.0",
"ember-tooltips": "^3.4.5",
"ember-uuid": "^2.1.0",
"ember-welcome-page": "^4.0.0",
"eslint-plugin-ember": "^6.2.0",
"eslint-plugin-node": "^9.0.1",
"loader.js": "^4.7.0",
"popper.js": "^1.16.1",
"qunit-dom": "^0.8.4",
"sass": "^1.30.0"
},
"engines": {
"node": "8.* || >= 10.*"
},
"dependencies": {
"drift-zoom": "^1.5.0"
}
}
```

If anyone has any idea about this error then comment or answer it. I will vote and accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I fix my issue by downgrading the node version from 17 to 16.